# WritableRaster java

Tags: java

I working on "mini photoshop" in java. I open jpg file useing this method

```
public BufferedImage open()
{
    fc = new JFileChooser();
    int ret = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        try {
            img=ImageIO.read(fc.getSelectedFile());
            img2=ImageIO.read(fc.getSelectedFile());
            raster = img.getRaster();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else 
        img = null;
    return img;
}
```

In this picture I make some change eg. sephia, sobel. But after this I want back to origin picture, I use for this method to do this:

```
public BufferedImage origin() {
    raster=img.getRaster();
    return img2;
}
```

The problem arises when I want again use sepia or any other filter because program remember earlier modification.

For example when i use sepia then back to origin and use sobel, program show me sepia+sobel, should show only sobel.

Answer (score 0):

Should the below line

```
raster=img.getRaster();
```

change to

```
raster=img2.getRaster(); ?

public BufferedImage origin() {
    raster=img.getRaster();
    return img2;
}
```

Comment: Hmm... my method origin looks the same. I want to add roster is change in other method for example `raster.setPixel(i, j, ww);`

Comment: and I can modify raster only in open method